# Laravel: Merge package config with filesystems config

Tags: php, laravel

Am building ecommerce backend platform and in my custom package i need to define new `Storage` which will upload files to `public` direcotry.

In my package i create new config file `ecommerce_filesystems.php` and in `ServiceProvider` i merge that and that is not visible in any config file.

I need to append new array to existing `Disks` array in `/config/filesystems.php`! Is that posible or i can only publish new custom config file?

**Service Provider**

```
public function register(): void
{
    $this->app->make(EcommerceController::class);

    $this->mergeConfigFrom(__DIR__.'/Config/ecommerce_filesistem.php', 'disks');

}

public function boot(): void
{
    //...
    $this->publishes([
        __DIR__.'/Config/ecommerce.php' => config_path('ecommerce.php'),
    ]);
 }
```

**My custom package config file**

`package/ecommerce/src/config/ecommerce_filesistem.php`

```
return [
    'ecommerce_public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path('/slike'),
        'visibility' => 'public',
        'throw' => false,
    ],
];
```

This above need to be merged with `<root>/config/filesystems.php` in `Disks` key

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
        'throw' => false,
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
        'throw' => false,
    ],
 

      /// NEED TO BE HERE 

],
```

I call artisan commands to publish vendor and also i clear config caches and nothing.

Comment: why not use it as a separate config ?

Comment: If i use as separate config how `Storage::disk(<name>)` will know what config file to read?

Comment: using on demand disk https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#on-demand-disks you can make this part of the code pull the disk config from the separate config that you publish

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are wrongly merging it. You have to use the full config path: `filesystem.disks` not `disks`.

```php
$this->mergeConfigFrom(__DIR__.'/Config/ecommerce_filesistem.php', 'filesystems.disks');
```

---

Based on your current code, if you run `config('disks');`, you will get back your config, that should be a hint

Comment: No that is not problem! Before i post this answer i try also that solution. After that i publish vendor with --force and when i check inside filesystems file there is no new custom array